# Stackoverflow Careers: Personal Website Merits

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, jobs

I have been invited with a resume filing discount on the site a while ago. I'm going to attempt using it once I'm done filling my resume on my profile with my reputation scores. However, I'm not sure what to fill for my website. Currently, my main website is still under construction. I have a personal blog under my domain, but it is not related to programming by any means. It's more related to personal life, careers, work/life balance, travelling, etc. Knowing this information, would you still recommend putting that particular website down, or would it be better to modify my profile with the updated website when I actually get around to finish off my webpage? I hope this is the right place to ask my question, as this is not directly related to system administration, software development, or computer enthusiasm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in the right place!

If you are willing to make your CV public you can use your public CV URL as your website.

I'd say whatever URLs give employers a better sense of what kind of person you'd be in the workplace are fair game.

Comment: It would give them a better idea of what kind of person I am, although not necessarily how good of a programmer I am.

Comment: @stanigator I agree, but there is always *some* crossover between your personal life and professional life.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure what to fill for my website

If you have a website that showcases your skills, ability, efforts in your field, etc, then use that.

If not, then don't.

There's no reason to invite potential employers to view your website if it has little to do with what they are interested in finding out.  There's a personal interests field, and you could fill that out with a variety of personal information, but you should again only post things there that will enhance your image.

The main reason for this is that you can't discern how interested they will be in your death metal band hijinks (or whatever you might be interested in that can be discovered from your website) until you meet them in person.  During an interview if it appears that you might improve your chances with a given interviewer, then you might broach subjects outside of your core skills and abilities.

But you needn't fill out every field in the CV just because it is available.

Comment: Thanks. It's just that the recommendations made it tempting to at least attempt to fill the field.